# Moving large amount of Cells from one Workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am rather new and fresh to VBA and I have had a look and cannot seem to find the answer I need anywhere (if I have been looking correctly).

It is a simple question but I would like to find out the best possible way to achieve it.

I'm looking at moving around 750,000 Cells from one Workbook to another (With or without formatting is not an issue)

What would be the best or quickest method to copy/move them over?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to copy the values is

```
Workbooks("Workbook1").Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1:C10").Value = Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:C10").Value
```

Alternatively you can copy a complete worksheet to another workbook:

```
Workbooks("Source").Worksheets("SrcSheet").Copy After:=Workbooks("Destination").Sheets(Workbooks("Destination").Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: Thank you.

I tried your first suggestion but got hit with a "Out of Memory Error" which I kind of expected due to it being a work laptop.

I know about the Second method but I have no idea why I didn't even think of it haha But thank you for the second one as that one works best for me! :)